# matching surf features - degree of similarity

Tags: matching, surf

I am using OpenSURF to find best matches in two images. It finds the matching points. I am wondering how I can know the degree of similarity between two matched points ((how strong the match is). I would appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is well documented in the literature, including the SURF paper itself.  You simply find the distance (e.g. Euclidean, Mahalanobis) between the descriptor vectors.  Since the squared distance is faster to compute (it avoids a square root), you might also see the dot product of the vectors used instead since it is equivalent to the squared Euclidean distance.

Standard practice is then to decide whether or not to accept a match based on this distance and a threshold.  The SIFT paper (Lowe 2004) gives a slightly more complicated way of accepting matches if I recall correctly, so you might want to read that too.

In OpenSURF, the descriptors are `float` vectors stored in the `Ipoint` class - so once you have called `Surf.getDescriptors` and populated the `Ipoint` vector given to the constructor, you simply get the `Ipoint.desctiptor` fields of a pair of `Ipoint`s and compute the distance.